# MAUI: Add-Migration -> Startup project targets platform 'Android'. The Entity Framework Core .NET Command-line Tools don't support this platform

Tags: android, entity-framework, xamarin, entity-framework-core, maui

I want to make an EFCore migration for a MAUI Blazor app.
But when using Package Manager or CLI i get an error because startup project targets Android.
I do not see this error in the tutorials i am following.

Comment: You probably need to specify `-StartupProject NameOfYourNetStandardProject` to tell the dotnet ef tool to use a different startup project.

Answer (score 0):

Migrations cannot be used inside MAUI project directly. The solution is to put the DbContext and Models in a separate Class Library project.

- Create Class Library Project and create inside it the Models and the DbContext.
- Reference the class library project from the MAUI project.
- Add the DbContext in MauiProgram.cs and reference the class library as the Migrations assembly.

When adding migrations, reference the project and startup project as follow:

```
dotnet ef migrations add Initial --startup-project ..\YourClassLibrary --project ..\YourClassLibrary
```

Credits to Asaad Iaaly: https://github.com/AssadIaaly/MauiSqlite